# Spring security oauth2 - Can't access /oauth/token route

Tags: java, spring-security, oauth

I've just begun to make an authentication server for my rest api by following this tutorial : https://jugbd.org/2017/09/19/implementing-oauth2-spring-boot-spring-security/. Everything went well until the very end where I just couldn't access /oauth/token route in order to authenticate.

I think I need a little more explanations in order to understand fully this authentication.

Thanks you,
Matthieu Meunier

PS : Here are my classes :

ResourceServerConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/secure/**").authenticated();
    }
}
```

AuthorizationServerConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer serverSecurityConfigurer){
        serverSecurityConfigurer
                .tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()")
                .checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()")
                .allowFormAuthenticationForClients();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception{
        clients.inMemory().withClient("android-client")
                .authorizedGrantTypes("client-credentials", "password", "refresh_token")
                .authorities("ROLE_CLIENT", "ROLE_ANDROID_CLIENT")
                .scopes("read", "write", "trust")
                .resourceIds("oauth2resource")
                .accessTokenValiditySeconds(5000)
                .secret("android-secret").refreshTokenValiditySeconds(50000);
    }
    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints){
        endpoints.authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
                .allowedTokenEndpointRequestMethods(HttpMethod.GET, HttpMethod.POST);
    }
}
```

Just below my Main

```
@Autowired
    CustomUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    public void authenticationManager(AuthenticationManagerBuilder builder) throws Exception{
        builder.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    }
```

And finally my CustomUserDetailsService and the UserService

CustomUserDetailsService.java

```
@Service
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    private final UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    public CustomUserDetailsService(UserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        return this.userService.findByEmail(email);
    }
}
```

UserService.java

```
@Service
public class UserService {

    @Autowired
    MembreRepository membreRepository;

    public UserDetails findByEmail(String email){
        return membreRepository.findOneByEmail(email);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @dur I did some modification and know I can authenticate myself but only if the password is not hashed. I still don't understand where the password verification is issued. Do you have an idea on how I can make the verification happens?

Comment: I can authenticate myself if I use a non hashed password from my database, otherwise I can't figure where the password is "hashed" before the verification when I authenticate :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the endpoint /oauth/token is secure,

So to call this endpoint you need to authenticate as a Client. To do this, according to your settings, you need pass client_id and client_secret on POST body (your settings allow client authentication form `.allowFormAuthenticationForClients()`).

Try call endpoint with parameters:

URL

```
{{host}}/oauth/token
```

HEADER

```
Content-Type application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

Post Params

```
grant_type: password
scope: read write
username: foo
password: bar
client_id: android-client
client_secret: android-secret
```

I use Postman to test

Comment: Thanks you I got it finally I was missing my client id and secret, turned out I had to put them in my header. I'll see if it work in the body of my request too. Any idea if one of the method is better than the other?

Comment: I believe it depends on the type of application (Web or mobile), but I prefer to use via header as well