# Spring oauth2 basic authentication

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, authentication, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I am trying to develop a rest api with spring security Using OAuth2 implementation. but how do I remove basic authentication. I just want to send a username and password to body and get a token on postman.

```
@Configuration
public class OAuthServerConfigration {

private static final String SERVER_RESOURCE_ID = "oauth2-server";

private static InMemoryTokenStore tokenStore = new InMemoryTokenStore();


@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
protected static class ResourceServer extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) throws Exception {
        resources.resourceId(SERVER_RESOURCE_ID).stateless(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
         http.anonymous().disable().requestMatchers().antMatchers("/api/**").and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/**").access("#oauth2.hasScope('read')");
    }
}

@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
protected static class AuthConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;


    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        endpoints.authenticationManager(authenticationManager).tokenStore(tokenStore).approvalStoreDisabled();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.inMemory()
            .withClient("client")
            .secret("$2a$10$5OkeCLKNs/BkdO0qcYRri.MdIcKhFvElAllhPgLfRQqG7wkEiPmq2")
                .authorizedGrantTypes("password","authorization_code","refresh_token")
                .authorities("ROLE_CLIENT", "ROLE_TRUSTED_CLIENT")
              .scopes("read", "write", "trust")
                .resourceIds(SERVER_RESOURCE_ID)
                  //.accessTokenValiditySeconds(ONE_DAY)
                  .accessTokenValiditySeconds(300)
                  .refreshTokenValiditySeconds(50);

    }


    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer) throws Exception {

        oauthServer
                // we're allowing access to the token only for clients with 'ROLE_TRUSTED_CLIENT' authority
                .tokenKeyAccess("hasAuthority('ROLE_TRUSTED_CLIENT')")
                .checkTokenAccess("hasAuthority('ROLE_TRUSTED_CLIENT')");

    }

 }

}

@Configuration
@Order(2)
public static class ApiLoginConfig extends 
WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{   
    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    ClientDetailsService clientDetailsService;


    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/oauth/**");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.httpBasic().disable().csrf().disable().antMatcher("/oauth/token").authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll();


    }
    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new InMemoryTokenStore();
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public TokenStoreUserApprovalHandler userApprovalHandler(TokenStore tokenStore){
        TokenStoreUserApprovalHandler handler = new TokenStoreUserApprovalHandler();
        handler.setTokenStore(tokenStore);
        handler.setRequestFactory(new DefaultOAuth2RequestFactory(clientDetailsService));
        handler.setClientDetailsService(clientDetailsService);
        return handler;
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public ApprovalStore approvalStore(TokenStore tokenStore) throws Exception {
        TokenApprovalStore store = new TokenApprovalStore();
        store.setTokenStore(tokenStore);
        return store;
    }
}
```

want to remove the basic authentication and send the username password in the body tag from the postman for get token

and I have got some problem
{
    "error": "unauthorized",
    "error_description": "There is no client authentication. Try adding an appropriate authentication filter."
}

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring security oauth2 - Can't access /oauth/token route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48750257/spring-security-oauth2-cant-access-oauth-token-route)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your **`@EnableAuthorizationServer`** configuration class in the method:-

```
@Override
public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer)
```

Try to add the following:-

```
oauthServer.allowFormAuthenticationForClients()
```

After you have done that you will have to call the oauth get token url as below:-

URL will be the same as http(s)://{HOST_NAME}/oauth/token

HTTP method type now will be **`POST`**

Header:-

```
Content-Type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

Parameters will be key value pairs in x-www-form-urlencoded in the body of postman

for client_credentials grant_type:-

```
grant_type=client_credentials
client_id=client_id_value
client_secret=client_secret_value
scope=scopes
```

for password grant_type:-

```
grant_type=password
client_id=client_id_value
client_secret=client_secret_value
scope=scopes
username=username
password=password
```

scopes will be comma separated here

Comment: grant_type = password